# Can i write all of my serverside inside nextjs?

Tags: node.js, next.js

In nextjs u can write API routes using the api named directory inside the pages directory, thus i was wondering if i can write all of my server code(api endpoint,database queries...ect) inside of NextJS instead of having an actual nodejs app running elsewhere?

Comment: Yup, you can. :) Note that Nextjs is an "actual nodejs app".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690747/next-js-api-is-back-end

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:** Yes. Nextjs is in fact an Nodejs app itself.

**The long answer**:

Depending on your apps usage and scale and the size of your team there are some nuances to consider.

If you use Nextjs for both Server-side Rendering (SSR) and handling api calls, it will effectively have two responsibilities.

This is perfect for small teams because the stack is relatively uncomplicated and all in the same repository (and module).

At a certain scale you might want to optimise deployments to gear towards either rendering or handling api calls. It might become difficult to keep both extremely highly performing - at which point a separate, specialised, backend might become relevant.